# Gráfico de dispersión de puntos PYTHON animación

Tags: python, matplotlib, animación

Estoy intentando representar el movimiento de una persona (los datos los saco de una base de datos que incluyen coordenadas y horas) y me gustaría que cada punto de la gráfica se mostrase según el tiempo (uno detrás de otro y no todos de golpe).

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

El trozo de código que llevo es:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()


plt.plot(X,Y)   
plt.scatter(X,Y,marker='o',alpha=0.15)

ani = FuncAnimation(X,Y)
```

siendo X e Y dos matrices con las coordenadas.

Comment: Creo que puede ser util `moviepy`. Mira ejemplos aqui -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moviepy-creating-animation-using-matplotlib/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Para lograrlo debes tener algunos módulos instalados en tu PC

Primero debes tener `FFmpeg` instalado en tu computadora (Guía de instalación [aquí](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows))

También debes tener el módulo en python `pip install ffmpeg-python`

Para este ejemplo voy a utilizar el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    A
0   156
1   139
2   133
3   39
4   33
5   50
6   24
7   19
8   35
9   165
10  209
```

El ejemplo funcionando con comentarios para que puedas entender cada parte:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML    #Esta sirve para visualizar la animación en Jupyterlab

#Definimos la animación
def animar(i):
    data = df.iloc[:int(i+1)] #Selecciona el rango de datos
    p = sns.scatterplot(x=data.index, y=data['A'], data=data, color="r") #El tipo de gráfica y los datos que se van a graficar
    p.tick_params(labelsize=17)
    plt.setp(p.lines,linewidth=7)

#Configuramos la figura y sus propiedades
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(np.min(df.index.values), np.max(df.index.values))
plt.ylim(np.min(df)[0], np.max(df)[0])
plt.xlabel('Indice',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Datos',fontsize=20)
plt.title('Ejemplo',fontsize=20)

#Creamos la animación
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animar, frames=17, repeat=True)

#Visualizamos la animación
HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

Resultado

[image: Animación]

[Aquí](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-animated-graphs-in-python-bb619cc2dec1) te dejo otro link con otro ejemplo más completo por si lo deseas revisar

**Nota:** El FFmpeg va a servirte cuando quieras guardar las animaciones